# How to add and remove values from ComboBox to CheckedListBox

Tags: c#, winforms, checkbox, combobox

What I need:
I need a ComboBox and a CheckedListBox with exact same values.
I have a Button to add values and delete values.

Here is my `Add` Button:

```
private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    checkedListBox1.Items.Add(comboBox1.Text);
    comboBox1.Items.Add(comboBox1.Text);
    comboBox1.Text = "";
}
```

and my `Delete` Button:

```
private void button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    comboBox1.Items.Remove(comboBox1.SelectedItem);
}
```

I would like to be able to delete the entries in the CheckedListBox without having to select it first, I only need it to be selected into the `comboBox1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're adding the same strings, you can use the [IndexOf()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listbox.objectcollection.indexof) method to get the index where the current string is located in your CheckedListBox and the [RemoveAt()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listbox.objectcollection.removeat) to remove it.
Verify that the `ComboBox.SelectedItem` is not null. You can use the [GetItemText()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.getitemtext) method to get the string currently selected. If the `SelectedItem` is null, you get back a empty string.

```
private void button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string currentItem = comboBox1.GetItemText(comboBox1.SelectedItem);
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(currentItem))
    {
         checkedListBox1.Items.RemoveAt(checkedListBox1.Items.IndexOf(currentItem));
         comboBox1.Items.Remove(comboBox1.SelectedItem);
    }
}
```

Method2:
If the Items it the two controls are located at the same index, you can instead use the `ComboBox.SelectedIndex` to `RemoveAt()` both:

```
private void button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (comboBox1.SelectedIndex >= 0)
    {
        checkedListBox1.Items.RemoveAt(comboBox1.SelectedIndex);
        comboBox1.Items.RemoveAt(comboBox1.SelectedIndex);
    }
}
```

Comment: Now, how can I make it so it removes a Row in my dataGridView as well? comboBox, checkedListBox and dataGridView will all have the same exact lines.
Only by selecting the item in the comboBox.

Comment: Different topic, different question. You'll have to describe how the DGV is filled (what method is used, if it's data-bound or not, etc.). You have to make another question, explaining the actual context.